# How do I scrape a specific HTML tag?

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm making a 3 letter username checker that checks against a web address where it's displayed in plaintext if the username is taken or not. It is inside of a `<pre>` tag and since the website is quite barren, there are no other `<pre>` tags or anything else on the screen for that matter, but I'm still getting the enitre webpage when I use other methods. Is there any way to only scrape the text inside of the `pre tag`? I'm just getting into working with python for the web.

Here's my code

```
url = "https://account.mojang.com/checkProfileName?agent=minecraft&profileName=kawsjkjkljgznxy"
    scrape = str(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(scrape)

    print(soup.get_text())
```

It spat out not the text I wanted to say the least, which is the only text displayed.

EDIT: Apparently, you have to be logged in to get to the output, which is really bad API design. The page should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8RV.jpg) when logged in.
EDIT 2: Imgur Link

Comment: you are looking for xpath and css.

Comment: When I visit the URL I get a login page.

Comment: @AndrejKesely apparently, you have to be logged in to access this page, I'll update the post to match. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: This `{"taken":"false"}` looks like a Json. you can use `json` library to parse it

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks! I'll try this, but now I have to find a way to get past the login. I think this is a metaphor for coding as a whole. You fix a bug, two more pop up xD

Comment: I recommend to look at `requests` library..it's more pleasant to work with `requests` than with `urlib2`

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it guys.